Jupyter-lab how to set cell style
As shown in the picture, I have seen this effect elsewhere, but I don't know how to achieve this effect? What plug-ins need to be installed? Or what configuration to enable, please tell me
As shown in the picture, I have seen this effect elsewhere, but I don't know how to achieve this effect? What plug-ins need to be installed? Or what configuration to enable, please tell me


Hmmm..my question to you would be what are you using that you aren't seeing this? You don't share details. Read How do I ask a good question? and note in several places you are advised to include details & specifics in your question. You should see that in the upper right corner of code cells in modern versions such as Version 4.2.5, 4.3.1. You can try several by going here and selecting versions and using the luanch binder badges. 4.2.5 I got from here presently.
